# Parameter passed by a reference behaves like a copy

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, copy

I'm having two pointers called `Character *current = nullptr;` and `Character *target = nullptr;`.

I'm changing them by a function:

```
void Position::Current(const Vector2f & mouse_position, Character *& current)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if ((mouse_position.x >= 245 + i * 164 && mouse_position.x <= 370 + i * 164) &&
                (mouse_position.y >= 56 + j * 201 && mouse_position.y <= 221 + j * 201))
            {
                current = &positioning[i][j];

                cout << "Selected: " << current->name << endl;
                cout << endl;

                current->health -= 5; //it doesn't change anything
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Target()` function is implemented by the same way.

Both functions select the right character, but it looks like those are copies of original objects (I cant change character's statistics) .

`Character positioning[4][5]` is array filled with characters. I can add them on specific positions by function:

```
void Position::Add(Character & character, int x, int y)
{
    if ((x >= 0 && x < 4) && (y >= 0 && y < 5))
    {
        positioning[x][y] = character; //is this a problem ?

        Character::position[x][y] =  true;
        character.x = x;
        character.y = y;
    }
}
```

`Position` class has only one object.

In `main()` it looks like this:

`positionx.Add(knight, 3, 4);
 positionx.Add(demon, 2, 4);`

and then:

```
if ((event.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed) && (event.mouseButton.button == Mouse::Right))
{
    Vector2i pos = Mouse::getPosition(window);
    Vector2f position = (Vector2f)pos;

    positionx.Current(position, current);
}
```

Current function should take 5 health from selected character, but nothing like that happens.

Where have I made a mistake?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I just had to make `Character positioning[4][5]` -> `Character *positioning[4][5]`

Then after clicking on a certain character, it finally started to behave like an original object.